# property verifyPhoneNumber does not exist on type 'typeof auth'

Tags: cordova, typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication, ionic3

I am using this plugin [cordova-plugin-firebase-authentication](https://github.com/chemerisuk/cordova-plugin-firebase-authentication)

I could not use methods in that plugin, for example verifyPhoneNumber `cordova.plugins.firebase.auth.verifyPhoneNumber("+123456789").then(function(verificationId) {
    // pass verificationId to signInWithVerificationId
});`
Here I get the error `Cannot find name 'cordova'.`

So I used this as

`firebase.auth.verifyPhoneNumber("+123456789").then(function(verificationId) {
    // pass verificationId to signInWithVerificationId
});`  added import as `import * as firebase from 'firebase';`.

But I am getting the error :

> property verifyPhoneNumber does not exist on type 'typeof auth'.

I am very new to ionic, What am I doing wrong here.

Answer (score -3):

Try doing this

```
new firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider().verifyPhoneNumber("+123456789").then(function(verificationId) {
// pass verificationId to signInWithVerificationId
});
```

According to the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider#verifyPhoneNumber)